# Membership ForgotPassword link

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

Looking to implement forgot password link on my MVC4 Membership. I have made a few changes to it as to what information I grab when registering and opened up the doors for google openAuth

I know i cannot provide forgot password for google and other open auth services but for my local users i would like to provide forgot password link.

Does anyone know any tutorials of best practices to go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a good white paper that discussess the ins and outs and some pitfalls:

[Best Practices](http://www.fishnetsecurity.com/sites/default/files/media/10WP0003_BestPractices_SecureForgotPassword%5B1%5D_0.pdf)